# Does cell phone radiation really cause cancer?

Tags: diseases, science-in-society, radiation

Is the radiation emitted from cell phones enough to possibly cause cancer?

Comment: You should ask this in another site in stack exchange, maybe physics? But to answer your question: no its not possible.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cell+phone+radiation seems to me that Google could answer this one.

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/569/do-mobile-phones-have-anything-to-do-with-brain-cancer

Comment: Do you believe **radio** — like normal FM radio or TV — or **outdoor heaters** or **light** can give you cancer? Those are electromagnetic radiation as well. In order for radiation to give you cancer, it needs to be **ionising** radiation. Cell phones use **radio** to communicate, which is 30 000 **less** energetic than normal light. Ionising electromagnetic radiation are Ultraviolet Light, X-Rays, Gamma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the microwaves simply don't have the energy to ionize the atoms in your DNA. Cancer can be caused by high-energy radiation such as gamma or x-rays. They have the energy to knock out an electron from a molecule or atom in DNA which leads to mutations and eventually cancer.

Answer (score -1):

Biologist Dr. Martin Pall, Professor Emeritus of Biochemistry and Basic Medical Sciences, WSU, says yes indeedy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4J141c8vfs